# Multiplication in finite field - matrix representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I have question regarding multiplication in Galois Field.

I know that if we have e.g. $GF(2^m)$ and we have its normal or polynomial basis, we can find matrix representation of the multiplication, however I was not very successful in searching for more details.

Therefore I would like to ask, if you know some good material/document/book regarding this topic, where it is possible to find explanation and clarification of this.

Many thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Finite_Fields_and_Their.html?id=AvY3PHlle3wC&redir_esc=y) by Rudolf Lidl and Harald Niederretier. There is an explanation about the representation of $GF(p^m)$ by means of *companion matrix*. The idea is to construct a (companion) matrix whose characteristic polynomial $p(x)$ is equal to an irreducible polynomial of degree $m$ in $GF(p)[x]$.

I also found [this article](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Wardlaw47052.pdf) by William Wardlaw.

However, I haven't found any resource with clear, formal, and rigorous explanation.